# Replace matrix elements with other matrix elements using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to replace all the elements of `zero_matrix` with elements of `x` but not sure which exact numpy function to use!

> P.S: I don't want to use python loop!

```
> zero_matrix = np.zeros((5, 15), dtype=np.int32)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)

> x = [[3822, 510, 4, 1, 20672],
 [3822, 510, 4, 1, 20672, 3822, 510, 4, 1, 20672],
 [3822, 3822, 510, 4, 1, 20672],
 [3822, 510, 510, 4, 1, 20672],
 [3822, 510, 4, 1, 20672, 4, 1, 20672]]
```

> My for loop approach:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    zero_matrix[i][:len(x[i])] = x[i]

[[ 3822   510     4     1 20672     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0]
 [ 3822   510     4     1 20672  3822   510     4     1 20672     0     0
      0     0     0]
 [ 3822  3822   510     4     1 20672     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0]
 [ 3822   510   510     4     1 20672     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0]
 [ 3822   510     4     1 20672     4     1 20672     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0]]
```

Comment: Does the loop method work correctly? _I'm trying to replace all the elements of zero_matrix with elements of x_ Replace how, according to what?

Comment: @AMC: Yes, for loops method works. You can copy paste that in check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Given that each row in your sample data is of unequal length, you can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to make a square array padded with zeroes.  Note that the array needs to be transposed to get it back to your expected shape. Then just assign the result to the equivalent location in `zero_matrix`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = np.array(list(zip_longest(*x, fillvalue=0))).T
rows, cols = a.shape
zero_matrix[:rows, :cols] = a

>>> zero_matrix
array([[ 3822,   510,     4,     1, 20672,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
       [ 3822,   510,     4,     1, 20672,  3822,   510,     4,     1,
        20672,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
       [ 3822,  3822,   510,     4,     1, 20672,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
       [ 3822,   510,   510,     4,     1, 20672,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
       [ 3822,   510,     4,     1, 20672,     4,     1, 20672,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Alright, this is a good solution given the matrix x has rows with size less than of zero_matirx rows. For example, let's say x has a row with 18 elements. In that case it will throw error like: ```ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,18) into shape (1,15)```

Comment: I would expect an error in that situation.  If that is not desired, you can always add `rows = min(rows, zero_matrix.shape[0])`.